# Laravel 5.7 HTML in Password Reset Email

Tags: laravel

There is HTML being displayed within the password reset email.  I'm running default email notifications packaged with Laravel.  Unsure why this is happening.

[image: Screenshot of html within password reset email]

I would expect it to look more like this:

[image: Screenshot from question #41400395]

Any help tracking this down would be appreciated.

Comment: Show the method and view that you use to sent the email.

Comment: IRC the password reset view use markdown. If you indented code in the view, the markdown will wrongly be interpreted

Comment: If you are using markdown, then **most probably it is because your markdown file is having indents**. Just remove all the indents and the mailable will render properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  I didn't realize I had to publish the laravel-notifications vendor files.  Once I did this, the email worked as expected.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```